# Not getting expected output for ternary operator

Tags: c, conditional-operator

Consider the following code in C  :

```c
  void main() {
     char *x = "abc";
     char *y = "defgh";
     unsigned int c=0;
     int len = ((strlen(x) - strlen(y)) > c) ? strlen(x) : strlen(y);
     printf("%d\n", len);
  }
```

I'm getting output as 3, but the condition in ternary operator `((strlen(x) - strlen(y)) > c)` is false, because this will be `3-5 > 0` which is false. Hence, the output should be 5. I couldn't understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `strlen` is `size_t`, which is an unsigned type. Thus the expression:

```
((strlen(x) - strlen(y)) > c
```

effectively expands to:

```
(((size_t)3 - (size_t)5) > 0
```

And `((size_t)3 - (size_t)5)` is not a negative number (there are no negative `size_t` values). It is instead a very large unsigned value (e.g. `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE` for a 64-bit system), which is in fact larger than 0.

Answer (score 3):

The `strlen` function has a return type of `size_t` which is an unsigned integer type.  This means that `strlen(x) - strlen(y)` also has this type.  So instead of resulting in a value of -2 you get a result which is a very large positive value.  This value is greater than 0, so the condition is true.

If you cast the results of these functions to `int`, you'll get the expected result.

```
int len = (((int)strlen(x) - (int)strlen(y)) > c) ? strlen(x) : strlen(y);
```

Comment: I don't want to cast. I wanted to understand the behavior.

Comment: @taurus05 I described the behavior, and you need to cast to get the behavior you want.

Comment: @taurus05 Two things. If you don't want to cast the LHS of your ternary operator, you can change it to `(strlen(x) > (c + strlen(y)))`. But the fact that you are putting the result into an `int` (i.e. `int len =` means that you are implicitly casting the output of the `strlen()` function anyway: from `size_t` to `int`, whether you want to cast or not.